# Communication between a web application and an android application

Tags: android, web-applications

I have a web application built on java and an android application. Both are deployed on different servers. How can i send request from android application to web application? Also, how can i send corresponding response from the web application to android application?

Comment: for this need to have web services through which your app and web application will communicate with one another.

Answer (score 1):

use REST api's (in JSON format).

Comment: I can't use web services as we are using J2EE 1.2.

Comment: why you cant use web services on J2EE?

Comment: because of J2EE version. Web services came in picture with J2EE 1.4.

Comment: oh.. sorry i don't have extra knowledge about J2EE. i can only help regarding Android or PHP.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the help of web API's . You have to create webApi's on your server and, You can use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in your android application to communicate with those web Api's.